# Is $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:(x,y,z) \rightarrow (y+z, x+z, x+y)$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Intuitively I want to say yes. I figured that the best way to go about this problem was to check if $T$ is bijective.

**Injective:**

$$(0,0,0) = (y+z, x+z, x+y)$$
We can rewrite that as matrix
$$\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
After evaluating you will find that this only has a trivial solution. Thus $ker(T) = \{0\} \implies$ Injective.

**Surjective:**

For this I would need to show that $im(T) = \mathbb{R}^3$, but I'm not sure how I would do this. I Think you should show that for all $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ you get $\mathbf{v} \in im(T)$ and vice versa. But I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: Hint: use the rank-nullity theorem

Comment: @Adam Wow that's really clever. Good thinking!

Comment: That is a map $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3,$ not $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use the rank-nullity theorem as suggested in the comments, or you formally invert the matrix, or after some simple manipulation you find directly that
$$
T(x,y,z)=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)
$$
with
$$
x=\frac{-\alpha+\beta+\gamma}2,\quad
y=\frac{\alpha-\beta+\gamma}2,\quad
z=\frac{\alpha+\beta-\gamma}2.
$$

Comment: If I wanted to find an inverse how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @StashuKozlowski: there's a general procedure to compute the inverse matrix which is too long to be explained here. Please refer to any linear algebra textbook. You may also want to check the Wiki page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix